# Why blank values in attribute table don't work as NULL in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, attribute-table, null, quickosm

In QGIS 3.4 I have a layer generated from the QuickOSM Plugin with various pieces of OSM data.

[image]

For lines 17-19 which do not have a value in the `"name"` attribute, I don't know why  `null` isn't showing up. I would like to select all the rows that have the name value empty. I tried using `name is null`, but that did not select anything. In settings, I have the option selected to say `null` in any blank values. My only guess is that maybe these values somehow are not empty, but they seem to be blank and I have tried writing something and then deleting it.

So what I would like to know is how I would select all rows of the table that don't have a value in the name column. Also, if someone could explain why `NULL` isn't showing up in the values that would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NULL` is not equal to an empty string. `NULL` is by definition an *"unknown value"* of which we cannot assume anything. Whereas an empty string is a string without contents. You can test for  `NULL` by using `"column_name" IS NULL` and for an empty string by using `"column_name" = ''`

Apparently in your data there are no `NULL` values but only empty strings.

What you can do is

- Replace every empty string with `NULL` by using the field calculator with  the expression `NULLIF("name", '')` *(QGIS >= 3.6 required)*
- Use `"name"= ''` as selection criteria

Comment: Thank you! I used your second suggestion and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Note: the `NULLIF` function was a lie. It's not available in QGIS as of right now. But since christmas is not too long ago, I made sure [it will be available in QGIS 3.6](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/8809).